# Phoenix - invald CSRF on AJAX post

Tags: ajax, phoenix-framework, elixir

I'm learning to use the Phoenix framework, and I'm trying to do an AJAX post to a controller action - however, I'm running into a problem with the CSRF protection.

For starters, I'm not using a form - just want to pass text from an input to the controller:

```
<input type="text" id="raw-input" />
<button id="send-button">Send it!</button>

<script>
$("#send-button").click(function(){
    var input = $("#raw-input").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/test/process",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"))},
        data: {"input" : input},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The controller (not worried about doing anything `input` yet... just want to verify a successful post!):

```
def process(conn, %{"input" => input}) do
    IO.puts "got it!"
end
```

And the router:

```
post "/test/process", TestController, :process
```

I pretty much lifted the `$.ajax` call from a Rails app where it was working fine, but it's not doing the trick here - running this returns a 403 error and logs `(Plug.CSRFProtection.InvalidCSRFTokenError) invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) token, make sure all requests include a valid '_csrf_token' param or 'x-csrf-token' header`.

Can anyone offer any guidance?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the CSRF meta tag in your html?

Comment: Thanks @Gazler - I was also able to resolve this by adding the meta tag as you suggest.  The thing that I was missing when testing that earlier was that Phoenix expects the parameter as `_csrf_token`, which you can even see in my question above.  Just missed that small detail... ok well, live and learn!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because Phoenix does not create a meta tag with the CSRF token by default. They're only included in forms generated by Phoenix's helper functions, and they're in a hidden input.

To get a CSRF token programatically in Phoenix, you can call `Plug.CSRFProtection.get_csrf_token/0`. There are many ways to pass this to your JS. You can add a meta tag to your layout to include it in every page but that might not be very efficient since it'll be generated for all pages. You can also just store it in a JS variable in the views that you require them in:

```
<input type="text" id="raw-input" />
<button id="send-button">Send it!</button>

<script>
$("#send-button").click(function(){
    var CSRF_TOKEN = <%= raw Poison.encode!(Plug.CSRFProtection.get_csrf_token()) %>;
    var input = $("#raw-input").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/test/process",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", CSRF_TOKEN);
        },
        data: {"input" : input},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome - just FYI, when I used your code I got the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` referring to `var CSRF_TOKEN = &quot;NXQ8YzQGLS0KPgskMTAXAAQeHVgaJgAAB8XZngDckuEVdiF2VPV1sw==&quot;;`. Thinking back to my Rails experience, I remembered that you can use `raw` to get around this - so the final working version is `var CSRF_TOKEN = <%=raw Poison.encode!(Plug.CSRFProtection.get_csrf_token()) %>;`

Comment: If one includes the meta tag in just the page that needs it, as done in the answer below, it won't be generated for all pages.

Answer (score 12):

Phoenix already has helper [csrf_meta_tag](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#csrf_meta_tag/0). Include it in the layout like so:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
     ...
```

And then use it in your js like so: `$("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")`

Comment: You're right, that's an excellent solution - I should've mentioned that I'm not using templates, though, so I doesn't apply in my particular case.

Answer (score -5):

If you want to skip the CSRF token check (in case you are developing APIs only) then you can comment out below line -

**plug :protect_from_forgery**

inside your respective _web/router.ex

Comment: This is a bad answer because it doesn't mention the dangers of disabling CSRF protection.